# Regex for Matching Apostrophe 's' words

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a regex to match a word that has or doesn't have an apostrophe 's' at the end.  For the below example, I'd like add a regex to replace the apostrophe with the regex to match either an apostrophe 's' or just an 's'.

```
Philip K Dick's Electric Dreams
Philip K Dicks Electric Dreams
```

What I am trying so far is below, but I'm not getting it to match correctly.  Any help here is great.  Thanks!

```
Philip K Dick[\'[a-z]|[a-z]] Electric Dreams
```

Comment: Why are you trying to match all lowercase letters instead of just `s`?

Comment: Every single word in existence either "has or doesn't have" an apostrophe. Perhaps you could tell us what expected results you want given the input you are showing.

Comment: Use `Philip K Dick(?:'?s)? Electric Dreams`

Answer (score 3):

Just set the apostrophe as optional in the regex pattern.

Like this: `[a-zA-Z]+\'?s`,

For example, using your test strings:

```
import re

s1 = "Philip K Dick's Electric Dreams"
s2 = "Philip K Dicks Electric Dreams"

>>> re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+\'?s", s1)
["Dick's", 'Dreams']

>>> re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+\'?s", s2)
['Dicks', 'Dreams']
```

Comment: Why use `{0,1}` instead of just `?`?

Comment: @CAustin You right, I forgot about it... I'll will edit the pattern. Thanks!

Comment: @YonatanBitton, thanks so much.  I'm trying to get this to work a slightly different way, so I have a string of text like "Philip K Dick's Electric Dreams" and I replace different characters with different regex expressions.  For example, the 'E' in 'Electric' will be replaced with '[a-zA-Z0-9]'.  Anyway, so I'll want to actually have a regex replaces the 's with '[a-zA-Z]+\'?s'.  However, I can't get that to match.  Below should match to "Dicks" or "Dick's" on regexr.com, but it isn't working.  What am I missing?  THanks!

Dick[a-zA-Z]+\'?s

Comment: @user576838 
You want to create regex pattern from text? Auto generate regex pattern for a text?

Comment: @user576838 
The pattern `[a-zA-Z]+\'?s` is used to search a word which: begin with letters, and after an optional apostrophe, and after the letter `s`.
This why the words `Dick's`, `Dicks` and `Dreams` were found, in the above sentences. But in the pattern `Dick[a-zA-Z]+\'?s`, there are already the first letters (`Dick`), so you need to skip `[a-zA-Z]+\ ` , which becomes `Dick'?s`. This will work.

Comment: @YonatanBitton, the catch is I don't want to match the whole word every time.  This time, it is Dick's, but next time it may be Marvel's or NBC's and so on.  So I'm looking for a regex that would match s or 's to replace the actual character in the word itself.  Am I making sense?  Sometimes I ramble, so I'm probably just not explaining it right.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the regex `(\w+)'s` to represent any letters followed by `'s`. Then you can substitute back that word followed by just `s`.

```
>>> s = "Philip K Dick's Electric Dreams"
>>> re.sub(r"(\w+)'s", r'\1s', s)
'Philip K Dicks Electric Dreams'
```